# how to append a column in csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv, data-science

```
Import geocorder as rg
for lat in data['Lat']:
    for lon in data['Lon']:
        #print(city)
        key ='#key'
        city = (rg.bing([lat, lon], 
                method='reverse',key=key).city)
        data['City']=data.append(city)
```

While trying to add a column in CSV file it shows an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `pandas`, you can add column for specific row using `row.at[rowidx, 'colname'] = value`

If you mention the datatype of `data`, it will help

EDIT:
As you confirmed you are using `pandas`, here's the code to access the row accurately and adding column.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('uber.csv')
print(data.info())
for index, row in data.iterrows():
   lat = row['Lat']
   lon = row['Lon']
   data.at[index, 'City'] = 'CITY' # Change to your rg function
print(data.info())
data.to_csv('newuber.csv')
```

And, if you are familiar with `lambda` functions, you could also do:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('uber.csv')
data['City'] = data.apply(lambda x: rg.bing([x['Lat'], x['Lon']], method='reverse',key=key).city, axis=1)
data.to_csv('newuber.csv')
```

Comment: can you pls elaborate it

Comment: thanks bro ....there is a little problem .....the server has limit so there is an error .The code is not run fully

Comment: Yes, as per Bing documentation, there are limits on the GeoCode look ups based on your plan. However, it looks like geocorder supports other providers such as Google as well. give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your whole code and also your error message? if I am handling with csv in python, I will use pandas library, if you are also using pandas, maybe I can help.

Comment: `import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import geocoder as rg
 data=pd.read_csv('/root/Desktop/uber.csv')
 for lat in data['Lat']:
     for lon in data['Lon']:
         #print(city)
         key ='#key'
         city = (rg.bing([lat, lon], method='reverse',key=key).city)
         data['City']=data.append(city)`                                                                             **TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid**

Comment: im using uber data so the lat and lon are in digits so i want to convert into coresponding cities_names and add to City column